# How do I stop only some instances of a coroutine in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I'm making a 2d game and I need to fade some elements in and out.

```
IEnumerator FadeOut(Renderer rend, float speed)
    {
        while (rend.material.color.a > 0)
        {
            Color objectColor = rend.material.color;
            float fadeAmount = objectColor.a - (speed * Time.deltaTime);
            objectColor = new Color(objectColor.r, objectColor.g, objectColor.b, fadeAmount);
            rend.material.color = objectColor;
            yield return null;
        }
    }
```

That's my FadeOut coroutine (the *FadeIn* script is this exact coroutine but inversed). The problem with this is that it bugs. For example if I enter and exit multiple times an area which needs to fade out, the whole game just blends black (or too bright). I solved this problem by using the**StopAllCoroutines** function.
One of the coroutine calls:

```
StopAllCoroutines();
StartCoroutine(FadeOut(tilemap,1f));
```

*I would rather to not use StopAllCoroutines as I'm using multiple coroutines in the same game, entering a fade area would just shut down a half of the system.*

I tried using **StopCoroutine("name")** (but from what I've found out, it's not compatible with newer versions of unity).
I also got on another thread on StackOverflow

Code from the thread:

```
routines[col] = StartCoroutine((DamageEverySecond(health, damageRate)));
[...]
StopCoroutine(routine);
```

Unfortunatelly this doesn't solve for my problem as there are multiple instances running at the same time.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @derHugo yes I totally know that. I searched about that thing on the web and unity did actually use the "name" instead of the instance (either that either some deceiving responses on the web). I also tried to save the instance of the Coroutine *(see the last code I linked in the post)* but it doesn't work well. When multiple instances are running in the same time, not all of them will be closed by the `StopCoroutine(routine);`

Comment: For further helping with a speciifc implementation ... show actual code ... in `StopCoroutine(routine);` ... what is `routine` and where does it come from?

Answer (score 5):

That

> Code from the thread
>
> ```
> routines[col] = StartCoroutine((DamageEverySecond(health, damageRate)));
> [...]
> StopCoroutine(routine);
> ```

that code does **not** use the `"name"` .. it rather uses an instance of [`Coroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html) which is returned by [`StartCoroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) and is exactly what you want to do:

```
private Coroutine fadeOutRoutine;
```

then when you start one you do e.g.

```
fadeOutRoutine = StartCoroutine(FadeOut(tilemap,1f));
```

and you can stop it using

```
StopCoroutine(fadeOutRoutine);
```

or if there are many routines you coud do

```
private List<Coroutine> fadeOutRoutines;
```

then when you start one you do e.g.

```
fadeOutRoutines.Add(StartCoroutine(FadeOut(tilemap,1f)));
```

and you can stop a specific (e.g. the last started) routine using

```
var index = fadeOutRoutines.Count - 1;

StopCoroutine(fadeOutRoutines[index]);
fadeOutRoutines.RemoveAt(index);
```